# summing up total from specific columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with the following columns

| bus Id | from | to | bus fare | costs | profit from trip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | ATL | ORL | 1000 | 700 | 300 |
| 145 | ATL | Miami | 2000 | 1200 | 800 |
| 145 | ATL | ORL | 1000 | 700 | 300 |
| 145 | ATL | Miami | 2000 | 1200 | 800 |
| 145 | ORL | Richmond | 800 | 300 | 500 |
| 152 | Ricmond | Baltimore | 400 | 150 | 250 |
| 152 | Richmond | NYC | 450 | 250 | 200 |
| 152 | Ricmond | Baltimore | 400 | 150 | 250 |
| 152 | Richmond | NYC | 450 | 250 | 200 |
| 165 | NYC | NJ | 100 | 40 | 60 |
| 165 | NYC | Philadelphia | 200 | 80 | 120 |
| 165 | NYC | NJ | 100 | 40 | 60 |
| 165 | NYC | Philadelphia | 200 | 80 | 120 |

I want to create a summary which counts the total of profits and total of costs from all rows if the bus ID is the same. This will help me calculate the most profitable route for each bus. How should I code it?

Comment: `df %>% group_by('bus Id') %>% summarize(across('bus fare':'profit from trip', sum))`

Comment: `mutate` option: `df %>%
  group_by(bus_Id) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(costs) + sum(profit_from_trip))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ `bus Id`, subset(df1, select = `base fare`:`profit from trip`), FUN = sum)
```